# Prometheus Adapter custom metrics HPA

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, prometheus, amazon-eks

I was following this walk through (partially, am using EKS.
https://itnext.io/horizontal-pod-autoscale-with-custom-metrics-8cb13e9d475

I manage to get scaled up one deployment with this http_requests_total metric.

Now, I am trying to add a new metric. I have prometheus server, and it already scrapes cloudwatch and I have `aws_sqs_approximate_age_of_oldest_message_maximum` value there for many of my queues.

In the similar manner to the mentioned tutorial, I am adding the definition of a metric:

```
  - seriesQuery: 'http_requests_total{kubernetes_namespace!="",kubernetes_pod_name!=""}'
    resources:
      overrides:
       kubernetes_namespace: {resource: "namespace"}
       kubernetes_pod_name: {resource: "pod"}
    name:
      matches: "^(.*)_total"
      as: "${1}_per_second"
    metricsQuery: 'sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[2m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>)'
```

vs

```
  - seriesQuery: 'aws_sqs_approximate_age_of_oldest_message_maximum{queue_name!=""}'
    resources:
      overrides:
       kubernetes_namespace: {resource: "namespace"}
       kubernetes_pod_name: {resource: "pod"}
    metricsQuery: '<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}'
```

Or some version of the bottom one. But, I can never see it in:
`kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq`

No matter what I try.

Any ideas how to move forward?
Thanks!

Comment: You are missing `name:` section in the second snippet, aren't you? This section and essentially `as` defines the name of a new custom metric to be exposed

Answer (score 7):

If you don't see the metric in `/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1` it means that the Prometheus Adapter couldn't discover it.

The Prometheus Adapter discovers metrics by using the value of your `seriesQuery` field for an [`/api/v1/series`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#finding-series-by-label-matchers) request to Prometheus (done periodically with a frequency defined by the *relist interval*).

Things to try:

- What do you get if you make the following request to Prometheus?

  ```
  http://<prometheus-ip>:9090/api/v1/series? match[]=aws_sqs_approximate_age_of_oldest_message_maximum{queue_name!=""}&start=<current-timestamp-sec>
  ```
- What do you get if you drop the following in the query text box of the Prometheus UI and press *Execute*?

  ```
  aws_sqs_approximate_age_of_oldest_message_maximum{queue_name!=""}
  ```

If you get no data back in either case, then you just don't have any time series in Prometheus that match your `seriesQuery` specification.

Comment: In your first request there is a redundant space after 'series?'.

BTW, I can't figure this one out, my custom metrics won't show up even though requests to Prometheus return proper results.

Any other tips on troubleshooting?